# Перестановка windows на ноут со стационарного

Tags: windows

на ноутбуке не работает клавиатура ( не могу попасть в биос ) на нем нужно переустановить на виндовс x64 xp 
когда я переставляю жесткий диск на обычный компьютер (стационарный и устанавливаю виндовс там, то на ноутбуке высвечивается синий экран( с драйверами что то ) 
как мне установить виндовс со стационарного компьютера на жесткий диск ноута , что бы он его читал? (если пустит в винду то я подключу usb клавиатуру

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Установить систему на одном железе, а использовать на другом практически нереально, т. к. программа установки прописывает на винчестер дрова для того железа, на котором производится установка.  Исключения бывают, когда на обоих компах использован одинаковый чипсет, и то с оговорками.
С другой стороны, USB клавиатура работает независимо от наличия системы на диске.  Если она работать не хочет, значит проблема с железом в ноуте, переустановка системы не поможет.